# How do I log on to JIRA in PowerShell using REST when basic authentication in plain text is blocked?

Tags: powershell, jira-rest-api

I've been trying to access our on-prem JIRA Server (configured with plain HTTP) using PowerShell `Invoke-RestMethod`, but I think I'm missing something.

The authentication header is created in base64

```
$cred = [convert]:.ToBase64String([text.encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("account:password"))
$headers = @{Authorization = "Basic $cred"}
```

Using REST, I then ask for the issue (without posting any property filter to keep the request simple while I'm learning).

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://jiraserver:8080/jira-software/REST/agile/1.0/issue/test-1 `
   -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -AllowUnencryptedAuthentication
```

This obviously fails, as I get back a reply containing a login form

```
<form action="/login.jsp"
    class="aui"

    id="login-form"

    method="post">
```

I do think I remember that basic authentication is no longer supported in JIRA.

How do I use OAuth in that case instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with another task that is well within the scope of Atlassian´s PowerShell module [JiraPS](https://github.com/AtlassianPS/JiraPS), I noticed a command called [`Invoke-JiraMethod`](https://atlassianps.org/docs/JiraPS/commands/Invoke-JiraMethod/).

It turns out that the module provides JIRA REST API access :)

So by setting up a JIRA session with the PowerShell module, I'll be able to use REST over an unencrypted connection.

Comment: You *can* use Invoke-RestMethod, just go to Atlassian site (https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens) to generate an API token. Use the token as if it is your password in the basic authorization header.

Comment: JIRA Server on-prem doesn't have a "manage-profile" URL. But my profile did have a PAT-feature, thx :)